# Get an list of lists with multiple attributes an obtain a new list with a specific attribute in C#

Tags: c#, list, dbcontext

I have a problem manipulating lists and I don´t remember very well how to do this...

```
            var allUsers = _userService.GetAll();

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
```

The var allUsers gets a list of a lists with this format

-> [[UserName1,X1,Y1],[UserName2,X2,Y2],...]

Note: I also have a db context when I can get a List of Users with Usernames but i need to put that to a new list() as well but i dont remember the methods to do that too

the result is a new List when im try to put all UserNames

-> [UserName1,UserName2,...]

How I do that in C# and if I call a table of any database will be the same??

Ps: I apologize if there are any spelling mistakes and if the question is very simple to answer that it becomes repetitive

Comment: You say you're getting users in *"this format"* but C# is strongly typed, so you've boiled out a lot of information. Please post the class definition instead.

Comment: I think it's not necessary to say the class, like, the _userService.GetAll() returns a List<Object> and the format is the one I said, the list of lists where I want to extract the Username attribute and put it in a new list. I don´t understand what kind of information do you need to add more

Comment: Who's the one asking for help here? This is how we do things here, we post minimal *but complete* examples that don't leave details to the imagination.

Comment: You are probably looking for the `Select` method in `System.Linq`.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I know the method Select and maybe that can help. So I assume that then fetching result.Add(allUsers.Select(t => t.Username) it can solve my problem, correct or what do I have of meter inside the select for all usernames?

Comment: You will want to use `AddRange` of List<T>, since the `Select` method will return a collection of usernames.  `result.AddRange(allUsers.Select(u => u.Username));`  or simply `result = allUsers.Select(u => u.Username).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `AddRange` of `List<T>` in conjunction with the `Select` method found in the `System.Linq` assembly.

```
result.AddRange(allUsers.Select(u => u.Username));
```

or simply

```
var result = allUsers.Select(u => u.Username).ToList();
```